# How to put Objective C code into Word (Office) with syntax highlighting

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ms-word, ms-office

I am writing documentation about an app and want to explain the code. 
I want to copy parts of the Objective C code from Xcode to Microsoft Word.
I don't know how to put the code with syntax highlighting (and maybe line numbers, too ?!) into Word.

Does anybody know a usable solution for this little problem?

Comment: Xcode copies also the RTF version of the source code into the clipboard. At least TextEdit and Pages can paste it correctly, but dunno if that helps you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Copy and paste works !

Nevertheless, make sure the option `"Copy colors and fonts"` in `Preferences>Fonts & Colors` is checked !

Comment: I know this is old, but I found this today when looking for a solution to this. The "Copy colors and fonts" option seems to have been removed from Fonts & Colors, but is enabled by default.

Comment: Yeah, just like JustSid commented, try pasting into TextEdit first - works for me.

Answer (score 7):

If you need this in Pages you can paste into textedit then copy/paste from textedit into pages.   I have yet to find a way to paste directly into pages and preserve the text color etc

Comment: Obvious, but worth mentioning: Make sure the TextEdit document is in "Rich Text" mode :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you copy from Xcode and paste into Word you get syntax highlighting etc as expected. You just need to reduce the font size to make it more readable and avoid wrapping etc. It would probably be a good idea to define a suitable Style in Word, e.g. "Code" which would have the required font size etc for pasted code.

Answer (score 2):

It supports these by default in Xcode 4. And what you need to do is to choose "Use Orignal Format" in Word or Power Point.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this in Pages, then a workaround is to copy in Xcode, paste in Word, copy again and then paste in Pages (That is if you have MS Word available).